# django path to view

Tags: python, django

hey i have a url path that i want to lead me to an application url file
but it says page not found

**here is my core url:**

```
    from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('store.urls', namespace='store')),
    path('basket/', include('basket.urls', namespace='basket')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**and here is my basket.url file:**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'basket'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.basket_summary, name='basket_summary'),
]
```

**and this is the view:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render


# Create your views here.


def basket_summary(request):
    return render(request, 'store/basket/summary.html')
```

my app name is basket , and i might add all of the files are defined.
whats the problem ?

Comment: What is the URL you entered in the address bar in the browser? It should end in `/basket`.

Comment: it does but still doesnt work

Comment: Oops...it should end in `/basket/`.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a trailing slash after /basket/.

[Read more about APPEND_SLASH in the official documentation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash)